# Solve Code dependency for using a variable which defined at later stage

Tags: dependencies, compiler-construction, structure, helper

I have a scrit to help with ThinkOrSWim trading. In the script, there is a tradePL variable which is working, now I need to use its value earlier in the script for stopSignal, problem is that it is not yet defined and there is code dependency which does not allow for re organising its position within the code. Here is the code to show the dependencies:

`input MaxTradeLoss = 300;`

```
def StopTrade = if (TradePL >= MaxTradeLoss and TradePL < 0) then 1 else 0;
```

```
def BuyStop = if !useStops then 0 else if state == state.long and (haOpen > haClose) and Flat or (currentTime2 <= 0) or StopTrade==1 then 1 else 0 ; # insert condition to stop in place of the 0<0
```

```
def SellStop = if !useStops then 0 else if state == state.short and (haOpen < haClose) and Flat or (currentTime2 <= 0) or StopTrade==1 then 1 else 0 ; # insert condition to stop in place of the 0>0
```

```
def CurrentPosition; # holds whether flat = 0 long = 1 short = -1
```

```
if (BarNumber() == 1) or IsNaN(CurrentPosition[1]) {
```

```
CurrentPosition = 0;
```

```
} else {
```

```
if CurrentPosition[1] == 0 { # FLAT
```

```
if (BuySignal) {
```

```
CurrentPosition = 1;
```

```
} else if (SellSignal) {
```

```
CurrentPosition = -1;
```

```
} else {
```

```
CurrentPosition = CurrentPosition[1];
```

```
}
```

```
} else if CurrentPosition[1] == 1 { # LONG
```

```
if (SellSignal) {
```

```
CurrentPosition = -1;
```

```
} else if (BuyStop and useStops) {
```

```
CurrentPosition = 0;
```

```
} else {
```

```
CurrentPosition = CurrentPosition[1];
```

```
}
```

```
} else if CurrentPosition[1] == -1 { # SHORT
```

```
if (BuySignal) {
```

```
CurrentPosition = 1;
```

```
} else if (SellStop and useStops) {
```

```
CurrentPosition = 0;
```

```
} else {
```

```
CurrentPosition = CurrentPosition[1];
```

```
}
```

```
} else {
```

```
CurrentPosition = CurrentPosition[1];
```

```
}
```

```
}
```

```
def isLong = if CurrentPosition == 1 then 1 else 0;
```

```
def isShort = if CurrentPosition == -1 then 1 else 0;
```

```
def isFlat = if CurrentPosition == 0 then 1 else 0;
```

`def isOrder = if CurrentPosition..` (rest is not relevant)

`def orderPrice = if (isOrder and..` (rest is not relevant)

`def TradePL = if isLong then Round(((close - orderPrice).....` (rest is not relevant)

As you can see the goal is to use StopTrade (which based on TradePL in the bottom of the script) to be part of the BuyStop/SellStop conditions (at the top) but I cant move it up as each bold parts of the code depends on the part above them. TradePL depends on IsLong and OrderPrice which depends on IsOrder which depends on CurrentPostion calculation which has the BuyStop/SellStop as one of the conditions - which I want to modify to include condition that relays on TradePL at the bottom.
Is there coding solution to it? Tried creating new variable but this doesnt help as the code structure and dependancy will alsways apply as each code depends on the one above him. Any help would be highly apprciated.

Error is of course for TradePL at the top not yet defind:

`No such variable: TradePL at 296:21`

`No such variable: TradePL at 296:49`

`No such variable: TradePL at 296:21`

`No such variable: TradePL at 296:49`

Thanks!

Im trying to use TradePL earlier in the script but it is not yet defined and the code dependencies dont allow me to re position the codes, also new variable wont help as the logic and dependancy will remain.